# jquery .addClass to future js generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I do something like this:

```
$(".field-validation-error").addClass('ui-state-error');
```

and at some moment something like this happens

```
$("body").prepend("<span class="field-validation-error">This field is required.</span>")
```

I would like this new added element to have also the class 'ui-state-error'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either add it yourself, changing that `.prepend()` call, or use [the `.livequery()` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery), like this:

```
$(".field-validation-error").livequery(function() {
  $(this).addClass('ui-state-error');
});
```

this will execute for all bounds `.field-validation-error` elements, and future ones. Or, if changing the stylesheet is an option, just include both selectors:

```
.field-validation-error, .ui-state-error { ....styles.... }
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: `.live()` is for handling events, something that doesn't happen here.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you just do this:

```
$("body").prepend("<span class="field-validation-error ui-state-error">This field is required.</span>")
```